# Viola Jones Face Detection framework

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, viola-jones

I have just started studying the Viola-Jones face detection algorithm to design a face recognition system. off all the things i understood, I have confusion regarding the phrase:"sum of pixels". Does it means sum of colors at given pixels or the sum of distance of the given pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you see something like that they're talking about the *value* of a pixel (its intensity). According to [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor), the value of a pixel is calculated as 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B. This is how OpenCV converts to grayscale, btw. So when they talk about the sum of pixels, they're likely talking about the sum of the pixel values in a given region (i.e. for a 3x3 region, take the value of each pixel and sum it up).

Comment: It is not "likely", I confirm that it is the sum of grayscale pixel intensities, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of pixels is the cumulative sum of pixels along the 2 dimensions of the image 
Please check cumsum function in Matlab.

For example: 
I = cumsum(cumsum(double(image)),2)

Check out this link for some good info on the [Viola Jones Face Detection](http://www.ece301.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=54%3aface-detect-matlab-1&catid=35%3amachine-learning&Itemid=13) technique

Good Luck!

Comment: The link isn't valid anymore!